# Hard perms and combs question

Tags: combinatorics

**14 students are to be seated in 3 rows of desks (first row has 8, second row has 10 and third row as 12), no student may sit next to each other?**

This question seems very hard :/ any hints? I have established that there are actually 4 seats in the first row, 5 in second and 6 in third because no student may sit next to each other. This means there are 15 seats total. However, it is actually (4)(2) and (5)(2) and (6)(2) because there are two ways for the students to be seated in each row with a gap (shift one right/left).
Will there be cases dependent on which row I choose to pick students from first?

I have so far something like
$$\binom{14}{6} \binom{8}{5} \binom{3}{3}2+ \binom{14}{5} \binom{9}{6} \binom{3}{3}2 ... etc$$but there are many cases if I do it this way and it seems wrong.
Any hints?

Edit: There are 6 cases I think. If you let the rows be a,b,c, you can have (a,b,c)(a,c,b)(b,a,c)(b,c,a)(c,a,b)(a,b,a)
Is this the correct way of thinking?

Edit 2: I think its probably wrong. My calculator gives a huge answer, I think it's unrealistic given the condition?

Comment: From the title, I thought the question was about salon hair treatments. I wondered what a hard perm would be.

Comment: I see a question mark, but what's the question? You want to know if it can be done? Sure it can. You can put 4 students in the first row, 5 in the second row, and 5 in the third row. What's so hard about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the people are all indistinguishable - if they are distinct, it shouldn't be much harder. I think you can do as follows. Since there are 14 people and only a maximum of 15 people can be seated, there is one row which is not 'full'. So this gives 3 cases, case 1 is that the arrangement of people is $(3, 5, 6)$, $(4, 4, 6)$, and $(4, 5, 5)$. Here the notation $(3, 5, 6)$ means 3 people in row 1, 5 people in row 2, 6 people in row 3.

Lets try the case 1 first. So $3$ people in row 1, $5$ people in row 2, and $6$ people in row 3.
There are $6$ ways to seat $5$ people in the 10 chairs of row 2. This is because you need 5 seats for the people to sit, 4 seats to place in between each person, and 1 seat can be placed anywhere else - there are (5+1) places to put this seat (these places are to the left of the leftmost person, to the right of the rightmost person, or in between any two persons). In general, as proven in the other answer, there will be $n+1$ ways to sit $n$ people in $2n$ seats.
So there are $6$ ways to seat the $5$ people in row 2, and $7$ ways to seat the $6$ people in row 3. So this is not a problem. The difficulty is the first row. We want to count how many ways we can put $3$ people into $8$ seats, without two people seating together. This can be done using the bars and stars formula, or the balls and urns formula. See [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/#:%7E:text=We%20discuss%20a%20combinatorial%20counting,groups%20is%20represented%20by%20bars.). In our case, there are ${6 \choose 3} = 20$ ways to seat these 3 people into 6 seats, without adjacency. Thus, the total number of case 1 is $20 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 = 840$.

Similarly, one can compute the number of case 2 is $5 \cdot 35 \cdot 7 = 1225$, and the number of case 3 is $5 \cdot 6 \cdot 56 = 1680$. Total answer should be 3745.

Comment: You are right, I will edit my mistake - thanks for the catch!

Comment: Hello, for the "difficult case" (the one that required stars and bars), I've noticed you can get the same stars and bars answer by doing (take row one, 5 seats for 3 students as an example) $\frac{5P3}{3!} +\frac{5P2}{2!} = 20$. Why would this work? Or in other words, why isn't $\frac{5P3}{3!}$ simply the answer?

Answer (score 1):

As already indicated, stars and bars is the key idea here.
Further, for each seating of 14 indistinguishable people, there will be $14!$
seatings of 14 distinguishable people.  The remainder of this answer assumes
that people are indistinguishable.  Further, this answer will use the word
**seating** to represent that the constraint of no two people side by side is
obeyed.

Lemma 1
There are $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways of choosing $k$ positive integers, whose sum is $n$.

Proof 
This problem is equivalent to the alternate problem of choosing 
$k$ non-negative integers, whose sum is $(n - k).$ 
From stars and bars analysis, this alternate problem enumerates to 
$\displaystyle \binom{[n-k] + k - 1}{k - 1} = \binom{n-1}{k - 1}.$

Lemma 2
There are $(n+1)$ possible seatings of $n$ people in a row with $2n$ chairs.

Proof
Since $n$ people will be seated, there will be $(n+1)$ *interchair* **gaps**.  
Further, since there will be
$[(2n) - (n)] = (n)$ unused seats, 
it is required that the gaps *sum* to $(n).$

Also, since seats $1$ and $2n$ may be used, but any other seats must involve people not sitting next to each other,
the first and last gap must be non-negative, while the other $(n-1)$ gaps must be **positive**.

The best way to attack enumerating the possible solutions of 
$a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{(n+1)} = n$ 
where $a_1$ and $a_{(n+1)}$ are required to be non-negative 
and the $(n-1)$ other variables are required to be positive
is to **creatively alter** the problem.

Suppose that the variables $b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_{(n+1)}$ 
are created, where $b_1 = [a_1 + 1], ~~ 
b_{(n+1)} = [a_{(n+1)} + 1]$ 
and, for $2 \leq k \leq n, ~~b_k = a_k.$

Then each solution to 
$a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{(n+1)} = n$ 
will correspond to a solution to 
$b_1 + b_2 + \cdots + b_{(n+1)} = (n+2)~$ **except** 
that, with $b_1$ and $b_{(n+1)}$ forced to be positive 
all $(n+1)$ variables $b_1, \cdots b_{(n+1)}$ must be positive.

Now, Lemma 1 may be invoked, which yields the enumeration 
$\displaystyle \binom{[n+2] - 1}{[n+1] - 1} = \binom{n+1}{n} = (n+1).$

Lemma 3
There are $\displaystyle \frac{(n)(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$
possible seatings of $(n-1)$ people in a row with $2n$ chairs.

Proof
Analysis contained in this proof will mimic the analysis
contained in the proof to Lemma 2.

Since $(n-1)$ people will be seated, there will be $(n)$ *interchair* **gaps**.  
Further, since there will be
$[(2n) - (n - 1)] = (n + 1)$ unused seats, 
it is required that the gaps *sum* to $(n + 1).$

Also, since seats $1$ and $2n$ may be used, but any other seats must involve people not sitting next to each other,
the first and last gap must be non-negative, while the other $(n-1)$ gaps must be **positive**.

The best way to attack enumerating the possible solutions of 
$a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n = (n+1)$ 
where $a_1$ and $a_n$ are required to be non-negative 
and the $(n-2)$ other variables are required to be positive
is to **creatively alter** the problem.

Suppose that the variables $b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_n$ 
are created, where $b_1 = [a_1 + 1], ~~ 
b_n = [a_n + 1]$ 
and, for $2 \leq k \leq (n-1), ~~b_k = a_k.$

Then each solution to 
$a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n = (n+1)$ 
will correspond to a solution to 
$b_1 + b_2 + \cdots + b_n = (n+3)~$ **except** 
that, with $b_1$ and $b_n$ forced to be positive 
all $(n)$ variables $b_1, \cdots b_n$ must be positive.

Now, Lemma 1 may be invoked, which yields the enumeration 
$\displaystyle \binom{[n+3] - 1}{[n] - 1} = \binom{n+2}{n-1} = \binom{n+2}{3}.$

---

The problem can now be attacked.

Given row 1 = 8 seats, row 2 = 10 seats, and row 3 = 12 seats, let $(X,Y,Z)$ 
represent seating $X$ people in row 1, $Y$ people in row 2, and $Z$ people in row 3.

As indicated in another answer:
you have to enumerate $(4,5,5), (4, 4, 6),$ and $(3, 5, 6)$ separately and add
them together.  
This is facilitated via Lemmas 2 and 3.

$\underline{\text{Enumerate} ~(4,5,5)}:$

$5 \times 6 \times \frac{6 \times 7 \times 8}{6}$ 
$=~ 5 \times 6 \times (56) ~= 1680.$

$\underline{\text{Enumerate} ~(4,4,6)}:$

$5 \times \frac{5 \times 6 \times 7}{6} \times 7 $ 
$=~ 5 \times (35) \times 7 ~= 1225.$

$\underline{\text{Enumerate} ~(3,5,6)}:$

$\frac{4 \times 5 \times 6}{6} \times 6 \times 7 $ 
$=~ (20) \times 6 \times 7 ~= 840.$

$1680 + 1225 + 840 = 3745.$

**Addendum**
This section (addendum) will present alternative (much less) elegant proofs for Lemmas 2 and 3.  This is intended to serve two purposes:

(1)
It provides a contrast between elegance and the (equally valid) inelegant examination of specific cases.

(2)
Some variations of a Stars and Bars problem might not readily yield to elegance.  In that event, the methods employed in this addendum may serve as a model for how to proceed.

Throughout this addendum, it will continue to be assumed that any **seating** must obey the constraint that no two people are permitted to sit side by side (i.e. next to each other).

Lemma 2
There are $(n+1)$ possible seatings of $n$ people in a row with $2n$ chairs.

Proof

case 1 : Seats $1$ and $2n$ are taken.
This leaves seats $2$ through $(2n-1)$, which represents $(2n - 2)$ places.
$(n-2)$ chairs will be used, which will leave $(n - 1)$ *interchair* **gaps**.
Each gap must be a positive integer, and the sum of these gaps must be $n$. 
By Lemma 1, this enumerates to $\binom{n-1}{n-2} = (n-1).$

case 2 : Seats $1$ and $(2n-1)$ are taken, with seat $(2n)$ unused. 
Analysis very similar to case 1.
$(n - 1)$ *interchair* **gaps** must sum to $(n - 1)$.
By lemma 1, the enumeration is $\binom{n-2}{n-2} = 1.$

case 3 : Seats $2$ and $2n$ are taken, with seat $1$ unused. 
By symmetry, this enumeration is identical to case 2, so the enumenration $ = 1$.

case 4 : Seats $2$ and $(2n-1)$ are taken, with seats $1$ and $2n$ unused. 
$(n - 1)$ *interchair* **gaps** must sum to $(n - 2)$. 
This is clearly impossible, so the enumeration for case 4 $= 0.$

Total enumeration of the 4 cases $ = (n - 1) + 1 + 1 + 0 = (n + 1).$

Lemma 3
There are $\displaystyle \frac{(n)(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$
possible seatings of $(n-1)$ people in a row with $2n$ chairs.

case 1 : Seats $1$ and $2n$ are taken.
This leaves seats $2$ through $(2n-1)$, which represents $(2n - 2)$ places.
$(n-3)$ chairs will be used, which will leave $(n - 2)$ *interchair* **gaps**.
Each gap must be a positive integer, and the sum of these gaps must be $(n + 1)$. 
By Lemma 1, this enumerates to $\binom{n}{n-3}.$

case 2 : Seats $1$ and $(2n-1)$ are taken, with seat $(2n)$ unused. 
Analysis very similar to case 1.
$(n - 2)$ *interchair* **gaps** must sum to $(n)$.  
By lemma 1, the enumeration is $\binom{n-1}{n-3}.$

case 3 : Seats $2$ and $2n$ are taken, with seat $1$ unused. 
By symmetry, this enumeration is identical to case 2, 
so the enumeration $\binom{n-1}{n-3}$.

case 4 : Seats $2$ and $(2n-1)$ are taken, with seats $1$ and $(2n)$ unused. 
$(n - 2)$ *interchair* **gaps** must sum to $(n-1)$.  
By lemma 1, the enumeration is $\binom{n-2}{n-3}.$

case 5 : 
Either seats $1$ and $2$ are not used, and 
one of seats $(2n-1)$ and $(2n)$ are used 
or (vice-versa).

If seats $1$ and $2$ are not used, then the case reduces to 
seating $(n-1)$ people in seats $3$ thru $(2n)$ 
which resolves to seating $(n-1)$ people in $2(n-1)$ seats. 
By Lemma 2, this enumerates to $n$.

By symmetry, the case of seats $(2n-1)$ and $(2n)$ being unused 
also enumerates to $n$.

Therefore, the total enumeration for case 5 is $(2n)$.

case 6: Seats $1,2, (2n-1),$ and $(2n)$ are unused. 
This is clearly impossible, since it would require that $(n-1)$ people 
be seated in $(2n - 4)$ seats, and clearly 
$(n - 1)$ people require a minimum of $(2[n-1] - 1) = (2n - 3)$ seats.
Therefore, enumeration in case 6 $= 0.$

Total enumeration of the 6 cases is:
$\binom{n}{n-3} + 2 \times \binom{n-1}{n-3} + \binom{n-2}{n-3} + (2n) + 0.$ 
This simplifies to the value given in the Lemma 3 assertion.

Comment: According to the formula in lemma 3, setting $n=3$ gives that there are 4 ways to sit 2 people into 6 chairs. But this can't be correct - if you try to brute force it you will easily get a number larger than 4...

Comment: @eatfood I found the flaw in my analysis in Lemma 3, and I will correct it.  My answer is now 3745, which agrees with yours.

Comment: Thats great! Then our answers should be correct.