# There are $333$ rooms and prisoners are assigned to rooms randomly. However, only $1$ to $100$ rooms get food

Tags: probability

I suppose you all heard the movie ''The Platform''. Not getting into unnecessary details, there are $333$ rooms and more or less, first $100$ rooms get food. Let's suppose that $100$ rooms are eating very well and the rest of the rooms doesn't eat a single thing. One more thing: Every month, every prisoner is assigned to a new room, randomly. And lastly, a prisoner can survive $1$ month without food.
What is the probability of survival for a prisoner with a $6$ month sentence?

Comment: This looks like an extension of your previous question.  What have you learned about that one?

Comment: Are dead prisoners removed from the lot or can they occupy one of the cells with food? Must every prisoner change rooms or can some of them, by chance, not change rooms?

Comment: Firstly, yes, this is an extension of my previous question. We will get to that later. Second, dead prisoners cannot occupy spaces but a prisoner can stay in the same room by chance, though it is pretty unlikely

Comment: What about water? Without water the prisoners can not survive one month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p = (100/333)$ and let $q = (1 - p).$

Let a *good* room (i.e. G) denote a room where food is supplied. 
Let a *bad* room (i.e. B) denote a room where no food is supplied.

If I understand correctly, the question is what are the chances that
a prisoner is never forced into a bad room, two consecutive times.

For convenience, assume that corpses continue to occupy rooms that are
randomly assigned, each month.  It seems to me that since only 6 months
(rather than $n$ months, for example) are involved, the easiest approach
is to forgo any attempt at elegance and simply identify all the
possible 6 month sequences that allow survival, assign a probability
to each one, and then sum the probabilities.

There are only $2^6$ ways of assigning either a G or B to 6 different
slots.  Of these 64 ways, there are 
$C_1~$ 1 way of assigning all B's. Chance = $1 \times p^0 \times q^6.$ 
$C_2~$ 6 ways of assigning 1 G.  Chance = $6 \times p^1 \times q^5$. 
$C_3~$ 15 ways of assigning 2 G's.  Chance = $15 \times p^2 \times q^4.$ 
$C_4~$ 20 ways of assigning 3 G's.  Chance = $20 \times p^3 \times q^3.$ 
$C_5~$ 15 ways of assigning 4 G's.  Chance = $15 \times p^4 \times q^2.$ 
$C_6~$ 6 ways of assigning 5 G's.  Chance = $6 \times p^5 \times q^1.$ 
$C_7~$ 1 way of assigning 6 G's.  Chance = $1 \times p^6 \times q^0.$

It is immediate that $C_1, C_2,$ and $C_3$ spell death, while 
$C_6$ and $C_7$ ensure survival.

Those probabilities, which are computed above, speak for themselves.  
Therefore, the problem **reduces** to a more thorough examination of
$C_4$ and $C_5$.

In $C_4$, of the 20 ways of assigning exactly 3 G's, only 2 of the 20
allow survival (namely GBGBGB and BGBGBG).

Therefore, $C_4$ is easily resolved by taking the chance of $C_4$, 
computed above, and multiplying it by $(2/20).$

The easiest way to resolve $C_5$ is to consider that survival is guaranteed
unless the 2 B's are consecutive.  Clearly, there are exactly 5 ways
out of the 15, where this happens.

Therefore,
$C_5$ is resolved by taking the chance of $C_5$, 
computed above, and multiplying it by $(10/15)$, re survival.

**Addendum**

I think that it is worth generalizing to $n$ months.

To do this, first read about Stars and Bars at the following link:

https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/#:%7E:text=We%20discuss%20a%20combinatorial%20counting,groups%20is%20represented%20by%20bars.

Then consider my (user2661923) answer in the following query:

[Hard perms and combs question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3825544/hard-perms-and-combs-question/)

To generalize, you have to look for creative ways of converting
a problem into a different but equivalent formulation, so that
this altered formulation fits into the Stars and Bars scenario.

Consider the case of the $\binom{n}{k}$ ways of having exactly
$k$ B's in $n$ slots.  This means that there will be 
$(k+1)$ gaps. 
Further, since there will be $(n-k)$ slots that do not contain a B,
the sum of these gaps must be $(n-k).$

Superficially, you are looking for all non-negative integer solutions
to 
$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_{(k+1)} ~=~ (n-k).$

However, you have the further constraint that $x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_k$
must be positive (else you have two consecutive B's, and therefore death).

A **very similar** scenario + analysis is discussed in the
mathSE answer that I cited.