# How does $2\le1+2\cos x\le3$ become $\frac{2}{3}\le\frac{2}{1+2\cos x}\le1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, fractions

> How does $2\le1+2\cos x\le3$ become $\frac{2}{3}\le\frac{2}{1+2\cos x}\le1$?

It seems that everything is being divided by $3$, as $2$ in the original inequality becomes $\frac{2}{3}$, and likewise, $3$ becomes $1$. But after dividing, we have:

$$\frac{2}{3} ≤ \frac{1 + 2 \cos x}{3} ≤ 1$$

where the middle term should be $\frac{2}{1 + 2 \cos x}$ instead of $\frac{1 + 2 \cos x}{3}$.

I know that the middle fraction gets flipped and multiplied by $2$. How do I use this to obtain the correct values of $\frac{2}{3}$ and $1$ in the new inequality?

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). If you have no idea, there are other ways to show context.

Comment: When you are writing your question, show the steps you have tried rather than listing all the different ways you have approached the question. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3825544/hard-perms-and-combs-question) of yours is good: can you do this for every question you ask from now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the reciprocal of our original inequality will swap the LHS and RHS around. Hence if,
$$ 2 \leq 1 +2 \cos x \leq 3 $$ then $$ \frac{1}{3} \leq \frac{1}{1+2\cos x} \leq \frac{1}{2} $$ (provided that $\cos x \neq -1/2$).  Finally, multiplying this expression by $2$ will give us the required inequality,
$$ \frac{2}{3} \leq \frac{2}{1+2\cos x} \leq 1. $$

Answer (score 2):

Think of it as two smaller inequalities:

$$2 ≤ 1 + 2 \cos x \Rightarrow \frac{2}{2} ≥ \frac{2}{1 + 2 \cos x} \tag{$\cos x \ne -\frac{1}{2}$}$$

as $a ≤ b \Rightarrow \frac{1}{a} ≥ \frac{1}{b}$.

The other inequality is similar:
$$1 + 2 \cos x ≤ 3 \Rightarrow \frac{2}{1 + 2 \cos x} ≥ \frac{2}{3} \tag{$\cos x \ne -\frac{1}{2}$}$$

and combining the two inequalities gets us the desired answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because $1+2\cos{x}>0$ and $$\frac{2}{1+2\cos{x}}\leq1.$$
The second is similar:
$$\frac{3}{1+2\cos{x}}\geq1$$ or
$$\frac{2}{1+2\cos{x}}\geq\frac{2}{3}.$$